# MySQL SELECT condition based on the last row and date interval

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to choose employees whose contracts expire in 2 months via MySQL.

This is my SQL statement:

`SELECT id,eid,end_date FROM contracts WHERE eid='861' and end_date BETWEEN NOW() AND date_add(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 month)`

The problem is that if the contract has been extended, so it no longer expires in 2 month - the above statement still selects the "old" row.

When the contract gets extended - another row or "contract" gets added with start_date and end_date different from the old one

How do I check if it expires in 2 month AND pick the last row.

I have also tried `ORDER BY end_date DESC LIMIT 1`

Please advise.

Thank you

Comment: What will happen when the contract gets extended? `end_date` will be changed??

Comment: Yes. When the contract gets extended - another row or "contract" gets added with start_date and end_date different from the old one.

Comment: what is the new column name  extended date

Comment: When the comments contain the single most important piece of information, it's time to edit the question. And/or better still, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do an aggregation first and identify the latest contract records for each employee.  Then, use your current logic to identify which employees have contracts expiring within two months from now.  This makes the assumption that the most recent contract/extension would have the latest end date.  If this be not the case, then you should update your question with what assumptions we can make.

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.eid,
    t1.end_date
FROM contracts t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT eid, MAX(end_date) AS max_end_date
    FROM contracts
    GROUP BY eid
) t2
    ON t1.eid      = t2.eid AND
       t1.end_date = t2.max_end_date
WHERE t1.eid = '861' AND
      t1.end_date BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do it with a query like this:

```
SELECT id,eid,end_date 
FROM contracts 
WHERE
    eid='861' 
AND
    end_date >=  NOW() 
AND
    end_date <= NOW() + INTERVAL 2 MONTH
ORDER BY
    end_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```